# shiny_1.3.2 VS shiny_1.6.0: Reactive context was created in one process and accessed from another

Tags: r, docker, shiny, future

I have a (simple, reproducible) app code using `future-promises` that works well in my undockerized environment:

```
promises_1.0.1    future_1.14.0     shiny_1.3.2
```

Inside docker:

```
promises_1.2.0.1 future_1.21.0    shiny_1.6.0
```

but generates errors when run inside the docker container based on `rocker/shiny-verse`.

```
## load libs ---------------------------------------

library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(highcharter)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
library(future)
library(promises)

## UI processing -----------------------------------

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Test"
  
  , tabPanel(
    title = "TEST in DOCKER"
    , sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        h1("controls")
        , br()
        , dateRangeInput(
          inputId = "dates_topics"
          , label = h3("dates")
          , start = Sys.Date() - 31
          , end = Sys.Date() - 2
          , min = "2019-06-08"
          , max = Sys.Date() - 2
          , format = 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        )
        , br()
        , numericInput(
          inputId = 'topics_plot', label = 'number of charts:'
          , value = 4
          , max = 12
        )
        , br()
        , actionButton(
          "run_topics"
          , label = "RUNIT!"
          , style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"
        )
      )
      , mainPanel(
        conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
                         tags$div("Please, wait...", id = "workmessage"))
        , textOutput("topics_alert")
        , br()
        , tabsetPanel(
          type = "tabs"
          , tabPanel('table'
                     , br()
                     , DTOutput('topics_tbl')
                     , br()
          )
          
          , tabPanel('Plot'
                     , br()
                     , highchartOutput("the_topics_plot", height = "750px")
                     , br()
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  , position = "static-top"
)


## Server processing ----------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  
  ## Tass.ru Topics ----------------
  
  dt_topics <- eventReactive(
    input$run_topics,
    {
      
      plan(multicore)
      
      min_input <- input$dates_topics[1]
      
      max_input <- input$dates_topics[2]
      
      ## update date range in ui
      
      updateDateRangeInput(
        session = session
        , inputId = "dates_topics"
        , start = min_input
        , end = max_input
        , min = "2019-06-08"
        , max = Sys.Date() - 2
      )
      
      plot_input <- ifelse(
        as.integer(input$topics_plot[1]) > 12
        , 12
        , as.integer(input$topics_plot[1])
      )
      
      dat_func <- 
        function(
        min_inp
        , max_inp
        , saved_metric_d
        , plot_inp
        )
      {

       start_time <- Sys.time()

       dat_full <- data.table(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

       output_tbl <- DT::datatable(dat_full)
      
       plo1 <- hchart(dat_full, "line", hcaes(x = x, y = y))
      
       proc_alert <- paste0('processing time: ', round(Sys.time() - start_time), ' sec.')
        
        list(
          output_tbl
          , plo1
          , proc_alert
        )
      }
      
      
      ## launch future to return
      
      future({
        dat_func(
          min_inp = min_input
            , max_inp = max_input
            , saved_metric_d = saved_metric_dat
            , plot_inp = plot_input
            )
            })
      
    }
)
  
  
  ## Output (async promised resolution of the future inside render...)
  
  output$topics_tbl <- 
    renderDT({
        dt_topics() %...>% `[[`(1)
      })
  
  output$the_topics_plot <- 
    renderHighchart({
      dt_topics() %...>% `[[`(2)
    })
  
  output$topics_alert <- 
    renderText({
      dt_topics() %...>% `[[`(3)
      })
  
}


## Run

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The logging I get after redirecting the Shiny log to a local directory reads:

> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:40519 Warning: Error in : Reactive
> context was created in one process and accessed from another.   [No
> stack trace available]

**I cannot figure out why the dockerized run fails, cannot reproduce outside of docker.**

@asachet, maybe you will be able to help.

Update. Strangely, I noticed that if I do not use libraries `DT` and `highcharter`, and instead use `data.table` and `ggplot2`, the example runs well.

```
## load libs ---------------------------------------

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(promises)
library(future)
library(lubridate)


## UI processing -----------------------------------

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "DIGITASS"
  
  , tabPanel(
    title = "Статистика по сюжетам tass.ru"
    , sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        h1("Управление")
        , br()
        , dateRangeInput(
          inputId = "dates_topics"
          , label = h3("Даты (вчера и ранее): ")
          , start = Sys.Date() - 31
          , end = Sys.Date() - 2
          , min = "2019-06-08"
          , max = Sys.Date() - 2
          , format = 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        )
        , br()
        , numericInput(
          inputId = 'topics_plot', label = 'Вывести график для топовых сюжетов (максимум 12):'
          , value = 4
          , max = 12
        )
        , br()
        , actionButton(
          "run_topics"
          , label = "Обновить"
          , style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"
        )
        
      )
      , mainPanel(
        conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
                         tags$div("Пожалуйста, ожидайте несколько секунд...", id = "workmessage"))
        , textOutput("topics_alert")
        , br()
        , tabsetPanel(
          type = "tabs"
          , tabPanel('Таблица'
                     , br()
                     , tableOutput('topics_tbl')
                     , br()
          )
          
          , tabPanel('График'
                     , br()
                     , plotOutput('the_topics_plot')
                     , br()
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  , position = "static-top"
)


## Server processing ----------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  
  ## Tass.ru Topics ----------------
  
  dt_topics <- eventReactive(
    input$run_topics,
    {
      
      plan(multicore)
      
      min_input <- input$dates_topics[1]
      
      max_input <- input$dates_topics[2]
      
      ## update date range in ui
      
      updateDateRangeInput(
        session = session
        , inputId = "dates_topics"
        , start = min_input
        , end = max_input
        , min = "2019-06-08"
        , max = Sys.Date() - 2
      )
      
      plot_input <- ifelse(
        as.integer(input$topics_plot[1]) > 12
        , 12
        , as.integer(input$topics_plot[1])
      )
      
      dat_func <- 
        function(
        min_inp
        , max_inp
        , saved_metric_d
        , plot_inp
        )
      {
        
        start_time <- Sys.time()
        
        Sys.sleep(5)
        
        dat_full <- 
            data.table(dates = seq.Date(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-07-01'), 1), x = 1:182, y = 1:182)
        
        dat_full <-
            dat_full[dates >= as.Date(min_inp)
                   & dates <= as.Date(max_inp)]

        output_tbl <- dat_full

        plo1 <- ggplot(dat_full) + 
            geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))

        list(
        output_tbl
        , plo1
        , paste0('Время обработки: ', round(Sys.time() - start_time), ' сек.')
        , dat_full
        )
      }
      
      
      ## launch future to return
      
      future({
        dat_func(
          min_inp = min_input
            , max_inp = max_input
            , saved_metric_d = saved_metric_dat
            , plot_inp = plot_input
            )
            })
      
    }
)
  
  
  ## Output
  
  output$topics_tbl <- 
    renderTable({
      dt_topics() %...>% `[[`(1)
    })
  
  output$the_topics_plot <- 
    renderPlot({
      dt_topics() %...>% `[[`(2)
    })
  
  output$topics_alert <- 
    renderText({
      dt_topics() %...>% `[[`(3)
    })
  
}


## Run

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**UPDATE**

I added this: options(shiny.fullstacktrace=TRUE)

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:41417
Warning: Error in : Reactive context was created in one process and accessed from another.
37: domain$onError
36: promiseDomain$onError
35:
34: stop
33: signalConditions
32: value.Future
31: future::value
30: withCallingHandlers
29: doTryCatch
28: tryCatchOne
27: tryCatchList
26: doTryCatch
25: tryCatchOne
24: tryCatchList
23: base::tryCatch
22: tryCatch
21:
20: evalq
19: evalq
18: doTryCatch
17: tryCatchOne
16: tryCatchList
15: doTryCatch
14: tryCatchOne
13: tryCatchList
12: tryCatch
11: execCallbacks
10: run_now
9: service
8: serviceApp
7: ..stacktracefloor..
6: withCallingHandlers
5: domain$wrapSync
4: promises::with_promise_domain
3: captureStackTraces
2: ..stacktraceoff..
1: runApp
Warning: Error in : Reactive context was created in one process and accessed from another.
37: domain$onError
36: promiseDomain$onError
35:
34: stop
33: signalConditions
32: value.Future
31: future::value
30: withCallingHandlers
29: doTryCatch
28: tryCatchOne
27: tryCatchList
26: doTryCatch
25: tryCatchOne
24: tryCatchList
23: base::tryCatch
22: tryCatch
21:
20: evalq
19: evalq
18: doTryCatch
17: tryCatchOne
16: tryCatchList
15: doTryCatch
14: tryCatchOne
13: tryCatchList
12: tryCatch
11: execCallbacks
10: run_now
9: service
8: serviceApp
7: ..stacktracefloor..
6: withCallingHandlers
5: domain$wrapSync
4: promises::with_promise_domain
3: captureStackTraces
2: ..stacktraceoff..
1: runApp

From earlier call:
176: base$wrapOnRejected
175: base$wrapOnRejected
174: base$wrapOnRejected
173: base$wrapOnRejected
172: base$wrapOnRejected
171: base$wrapOnRejected
170: base$wrapOnRejected
169: base$wrapOnRejected
168: base$wrapOnRejected
167: base$wrapOnRejected
166: base$wrapOnRejected
165: base$wrapOnRejected
164: base$wrapOnRejected
163: base$wrapOnRejected
162: domain$wrapOnRejected
161: promiseDomain$onThen
```

It seems all is very confusing, BUT:

I did an even simpler reproducible app without libraries DT and highcharter; using instead ggplot2 and data.table (and corresponding render... functions), and it worked as a charm.

And I noticed that when I install DT and highcharter during an image building (I had to install them as they are out of the docker image scope) I get several dependency installation failures, and everything is fine otherwise (ggplot2 and data.table are part of the image).

I will take time to dig into what exactly fails.

Noting, though, that I do not have the logs about any library failing to start after calling library(...). Hm.

Update1: app fails when using DT library with ggplot2, no errors during installation.

Update2: app works when not using DT library, but with the highcharter, and there are some errors (hmm) during installation.

**So, any combination without DT : data.table & ggplot; data.table & highcharter works, and any combination wit the DT does not.**

What is your opinion, how can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Could you try to make the example a bit more minimal? Then it's easier to help you, thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I have done that. Just push the RUNIT! button and you expect to get a table, a plot. I removed xlsx package.